# Reduce duplication while accessing Visual Studio services

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If you write a VS extension, you can get access to VS services with the IServiceProvider interface:

```
var vsUIShell = (IVsUIShell)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsVsUIShell));
vsUIShell.SetWaitCursor(); // for example
```

To reduce duplication every time I need this, I created a class like this:

```
static class VisualStudioServices
{
    public static IVsUIShell UIShell { get { return vsUIShell.Service; } } 
    static readonly LazyService<SVsUIShell, IVsUIShell> vsUIShell = new LazyService<SVsUIShell, IVsUIShell>();

    class LazyService<TService, T>
    {
        static T GetService()
        {
            return (T)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(TService));
        }

        readonly Lazy<T> serviceLazy = new Lazy<T>(GetService);

        public T Service { get { return this.serviceLazy.Value; } }
    }
}
```

To add a new service to the list, I have to mention its name 8 time (assuming the Service type and the interface type are the same, which is not always true).

I'm looking for a way to reduce this duplication further. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Your current design will potentially make unit testing code which uses it hard. Consider making the `VisualStudioServices` class non-static and create an interface for it. You could then inject the `ServiceProvider` as a dependency rather having an implicit dependency on the static `GlobalProvider`. Something like this:

```
interface IVisualStudioServices
{
    IVsUIShell UIShell { get; }
}

class VisualStudioServices : IVisualStudioServices
{
    public IVsUIShell UIShell { get { return _VsUiShell.Service; } }

    private readonly LazyService<SVsUIShell, IVsUIShell> _VsUiShell; 

    public VisualStudioServices(ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _VsUiShell = new LazyService<SVsUIShell, IVsUIShell>(serviceProvider);
    }

    class LazyService<TService, T>
    {
        ServiceProvider _ServiceProvider;
        LazyService(ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        readonly Lazy<T> serviceLazy = new Lazy<T>(() => (T)_ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(TService)));

        public T Service { get { return serviceLazy.Value; } }
    }
}
```

Any code requiring access to it should have a dependency on `IVisualStudioServices` which can be easily mocked out.

Comment: Yeah, unit testing is a valid concern. At least the "before" code was no worse. And as usual, difficult-to-test equals needs-refactoring, and your suggestion is a good first step. However, at this point, I'm happy with the ease of use of making everything static. If I really do need to redirect services for testing, I'll probably do something like `class VSS { public static ServiceProvider ServiceProvider = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider }`, at least until the rest of the code improves.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one option is to use reflection to instantiate all the static fields:

```
    static VisualStudioServices()
    {
        var fields = typeof(VisualStudioServices).GetFields(bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            field.SetValue(null, field.FieldType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] { }));
        }
    }
```

That reduces the duplication of service name from 8 to 6.

I do feel a little uncomfortable using reflection in a static ctor.

I also think it makes the code slightly obfuscated.